# Better way of initialising List of abstract class with inheriting class names

Tags: java, android, oop, inheritance, abstract

Possibly duplicate, I have an abstract class called FormField which contains some common properties like field value, field label, etc.

My application renders fields dynamically based on an APIs result. So, I can get a JSON which says fieldX of type String, fieldY of type Date, etc. Based on the type I want to automatically render the correct field. I was already able to abstract the logic using an abstract class with static blocks. The abstract class has code like:

```
// Common fields
public String label;
public String value;

public static Map<String, Class> fieldTypes = new HashMap<>();

static {
    FormField.fieldTypes.put("String", StringField.class);
    FormField.fieldTypes.put("Date", DateField.class);
}
```

I originally wanted to put the static block in StringField, DateField to add themselves automatically to the fieldTypes array in their parent FormField abstract class but that didn't work since I do not explicitly call these field type classes anywhere so their static blocks never get called at all. I figured the alternative would be to just initialize each inside the FormField static block.

The way the app works, it fetches the data from the API and for each field it calls a create method which takes the type identification string i.e. String, Date and based on that my FormField class initializes the code using this:

```
public static FormField create(String type, String label) {
    Class aClass = fieldTypes.get(type);
    if(aClass == null)
        return null;

    FormField field = null;
    try {
        field = (FormField) aClass.newInstance();
        field.label = label;
        return field;
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then it calls the render method which renders the UI and does further operations. I want to eliminate the static block and want hashmap to fill itself automatically whenever I create (not initialize) a new concrete class that extends it. This would help me to create new concrete classes whenever my business logic needs it i.e. tomorrow I can add any new field type such as photo and just write the specific logic for that rather than having to add a line to the static block each time. I wouldn't mind a better solution which eliminates fieldTypes hashMap too. I know there's some way through reflection to go thro the entire 'fieldTypes' subpackage and initialize one after another but I don't want that (nor do I know how it would be coded) since I feel is bad practice. Any better solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two solutions for this problem:

1) This requires an external lib: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections
Using this libray you can get all instances of a parent class, I assume Field as follows:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("your.project.fields");
Set<Class<? extends Field>> allClasses = 
     reflections.getSubTypesOf(Field.class);
```

For your case, whenever you introduce a new class to your codebase, this reflective code runs, discovers the class and use it accordingly.

2) Whenever you introduce a new class, you update a file, which contains all BlahField classes. You can initialize your map using this class but, I have to admit that this is less intriguing.